# ECT and adding created by and updated by

Tags: 2010, bcs, external-content-type

I'm using BCS and ECT's to connect to external DB. Is it possible to record the user who has updated or created the record in the DB?
I'm not using SSS at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to find out the user who has updated the record. You try checking out the "Execute" and "set permissions" in the Business Data Connectivity service application .